# Get all 4-character combinations of a given alphabet

Tags: java, permutation, combinations

let's say `alphabet = "abcd1234"`
I would want all combinations that have 4 digits.
I dont want to go through all permutations and choose only those which are 4 characters long Since the alphabet could be big.

EDIT: this is what I have so far

```
String alpha = "abcdefg"; 

        for (int i = 0 ; i < alpha.length() ; i++) {
            for (int j = i ; j < alpha.length()-i ; j++) 
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(alpha.charAt(i)) + String.valueOf(alpha.charAt(j))   );   
        }
```

Unfortunately I get only a 2 character word. And I cant get it to print 4 character words using the same structure of loops.

Comment: By not showing the fruits of your labors, you imply that you're too lazy to do it yourself or not smart enough. Please prove these assumptions wrong by showing what you've done.

Comment: "N choose K" problems are amply discussed on several websites, is this what you want? Like Andrzej asked... what problem are you facing right now?

Comment: Please find my accomplishment in the EDIT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly - all combinations aaaa through to 4444 - then this will work. It is "scalable" - doesn't require a nested loop per character.

```
String alpha = "abcd1234";
char[] seq = alpha.toCharArray();

int length = 4;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("    ");

int[] pos = new int[length];
int total = (int) Math.pow(alpha.length(), length);
for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < length; x++) {
        if (pos[x] == seq.length) {
            pos[x] = 0;
            if (x + 1 < length) {
                pos[x + 1]++;
            }
        }
        builder.setCharAt(x, seq[pos[x]]);
    }
    pos[0]++;

    System.out.println(builder.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest - if the number of digits is small and fixed - would be simple enumeration. Just iterate over the members of the alphabet.

From the name alphabet I assume that every character in this string is unique but can occur several times in the solution. If not an additional check that `i1 != i2` and so on must be performed before accepting a permutation.

```
int alphaLen = alphabet.length();
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < alphaLen; ++i1) {
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < alphaLen; ++i2) {
        for (int i3 = 0; i3 < alphaLen; ++i3) {
            for (int i4 = 0; i4 < alphaLen; ++i4) {
                foo(alphabet.charAt(i1) + alphabet.charAt(i2) + alphabet.charAt(i3) + alphabet.charAt(i4));
            }
        }
    }
}
```