# Make this function take strings of arbitrary length

Tags: python, python-3.x

This function takes a string of digits and a target integer and prints all possible ways to insert operators to reach the desired target. The output must in all cases contain all the digits in order; none may be omitted.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def find_expressions(digits, target):
    if not (isinstance(digits, str) or isinstance(digits, list)) or not isinstance(target, int):
        raise TypeError
    if len(digits) != 5:
        raise TypeError('digits must be of length 5')
    solutions = []
    operators = ('', ' + ', ' - ', ' * ', ' / ')
    for i in operators:
        for j in operators:
            for k in operators:
                for l in operators:
                    s = digits[0] + i + digits[1] + j + digits[2] + k + digits[3] + l + digits[4]
                    try:
                        if eval(s) == target:
                            solutions.append(s + ' == {}'.format(target))
                    except (ZeroDivisionError, SyntaxError):
                        pass
    print('\n'.join(solutions))
```

It isn't pretty, but it works. The problem is that it only takes strings of length 5. How can I make it take strings of arbitrary length? (E.g., calling `find_expressions('12345678', 2)` should be valid.) I'm thinking I need to replace the `for` loops with recursion, but I'm at a loss as to how to accomplish this.

## Example Output

Calling `find_expressions('75228', 5)` prints:

```
7 + 5 + 2 / 2 - 8 == 5
7 * 5 - 22 - 8 == 5
7 * 5 - 2 - 28 == 5
```

## Caveat

I'm not satisfied with the whole brute-force approach I'm taking by looping over every possibility. If there's a better algorithm overall, I'd like to hear about it. *However,* this question is about making this function take arbitrary-length input while making the smallest possible changes.

Comment: Have you explored the `itertools` module?

Comment: Yes, I have, but I didn't see anything that appeared like it would work. It's quite likely that I'm overlooking something, but for the life of me I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Where do the two digit numbers come from shown in your example output?

Comment: @martineau: one of the operators is the empty string, i.e., a straight concatenation :) It works for `find_expressions ([1,2,3,4], 1234)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools

def find_expressions(digits, target):
    if not (isinstance(digits, str) or isinstance(digits, list)) or not isinstance(target, int):
        raise TypeError

    solutions = []
    operators = ('', ' + ', ' - ', ' * ', ' / ')
    for ops in itertools.product(operators, repeat=len(digits)-1):
        s = digits[0] + ''.join(op + digit for op, digit in zip(ops, digits[1:]))
        try:
            if eval(s) == target:
                solutions.append(s + ' == {}'.format(target))
        except (ZeroDivisionError, SyntaxError):
            pass
    print('\n'.join(solutions))
```

Comment: I edited the question to clarify it. This approach only generates pairs, instead of replicating the functionality of the for loops. For the example input I added above, I get `7 - 2 == 5`, which is invalid because it doesn't contain all the digits in the input.

Comment: @ScottSeverance I have added the comparison with target and verified that it outputs exactly the same as your test case. Can you provide another test case that fails? [I get the same result on ideone](http://ideone.com/7swBjk).

Comment: Your edited version appears to me like it will work. Meanwhile, I played with `itertools.product` on my own and came up with my own solution base on the ideas in the first version of your post which is broadly similar to yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to get all *possible permutations* of the sequence `+-*/` – including duplicates, so the first sequence needs to be `++++`; its length should be `len(digits)-1`, because for *n* digits, you need `n - 1` operators in between.

The total number of permutations is `operators ** positions`; that is, every operator can appear in every single position. I don't see any handy shortcut for not actually *testing* all possibilities.

The following is loosely based on [Get all 4-character combinations of a given alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671111/get-all-4-character-combinations-of-a-given-alphabet); without the interjection of the digits and with the `# print ..` lines enabled, you will see it shows the entire list.

If your input may or may not be strings, use `str(digits[x])` so the string concatenation does not barf.

The following code

```
def find_expressions(digits, target):
    if not (isinstance(digits, str) or isinstance(digits, list)) or not isinstance(target, int):
        raise TypeError
    solutions = []
    operators = ('', ' + ', ' - ', ' * ', ' / ')
    used = [0] * (len(digits)-1)
    for i in range(len(operators)**(len(digits)-1)):
      attempt = str(digits[0])
      for j in range(1,len(digits)):
        attempt += operators[used[j-1]] + str(digits[j])
        # print (operators[used[j-1]], end="")
      # print ()
      for j in range(len(digits)-1):
        used[j] += 1
        if used[j] >= len(operators):
          used[j] = 0
        else:
          break

      try:
        if eval(attempt) == target:
          print (attempt, '==', eval(attempt))
      except (ZeroDivisionError, SyntaxError):
        pass

find_expressions ([7,5,2,2,8], 5)
```

shows

```
7 * 5 - 2 - 28 == 5
7 * 5 - 22 - 8 == 5
7 + 5 + 2 / 2 - 8 == 5.0
```

(where the last one prints as float because the `/` makes it so).